# How to make function decorators with user input

Tags: python, function, decorator

I made function that wraps text with 3 decorators.But i have issue with user input.
How to make it?

```
def bold(fn):
    def wrapper():
        return "<b>" + fn() + "</b>"
    return wrapper

def italic(fn):
    def wrapper():
        return "<i>" + fn() + "</i>"
    return wrapper

def underline(fn):
    def wrapper():
        return "<u>" + fn() + "</u>"
    return wrapper


@bold
@italic
@underline
def get_text():
    return "hello world"

print(get_text())
```

Comment: "But i have issue with user input." sounds incomprehensible and vague. Please tell us more about it and attach your code where you are trying to solve this problem

Comment: Change `get_text()` to `return input()`.

Comment: @martineau looks fine, thank you

Comment: That's good to hear, but it was just a lucky guess — in the future please be more specific about what's wrong when asking questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the parameter to the wrapper function too.

```
def bold(fn):
    def wrapper(text):
        return "<b>" + fn(text) + "</b>"
    return wrapper

def italic(fn):
    def wrapper(text):
        return "<i>" + fn(text) + "</i>"
    return wrapper

def underline(fn):
    def wrapper(text):
        return "<u>" + fn(text) + "</u>"
    return wrapper


@bold
@italic
@underline
def get_text(text):
    return text

usrInput = input()
print(get_text(usrInput))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_bold(function):
    def wrapper():
        return "<b>" + function() + "</b>"
    return wrapper

def make_emphasis(function):
    def wrapper():
        return "<em>" + function() + "</em>"
    return wrapper

def make_underlined(function):
    def wrapper():
        return "<u>" + function() + "</u>"
    return wrapper

@app.route("/bye")
@make_bold
@make_italic
@make_underline
def bye():
    return "<p>Bye!</p>"
```

Comment: You can help OP by clarifying your amendments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).